# How to copy links of answers and comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, hyperlinks

I've seen on SE sites where people post a link to some answer or comment, so that when you click on it, you're taken directly to that post and even highlights for a split second. I would like to know how I can obtain such a URL to link to any given answer or comment. I know if it's something which showed up in my inbox, I could copy it from there. But what if it was never in my inbox? How would I obtain the URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To copy answer's link, tap "share" under the answer and copy the link that will appear.

[image]

To copy a link to a comment, write-click the comment date and choose "copy link".

[image]

Comment: ...I feel like an idiot for not thinking of the `share`  link, but the comments was even more mysterious.

Comment: That comment link method is one of the most devious I've ever seen - who would even think of clicking the date to get a link?

Comment: @metacubed At least it's not one of those easter egg hunts, where you have to hover the mouse over an invisible button that didn't activate in the top-right few pixels of the comment and triple click.

Comment: @JerryDodge now _that_ would have been fun! :)

Comment: ...while holding `ctrl` + `alt` + `shift` + `F12` + `C` - using your nose for `F12`...